# Update vti_ property

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I use CSOM and I'm trying to find a way how to change **vti_contenttypeorder** property for a list item.

Does anyone know some workaround how I can to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround using [lists.asmx web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists(v=office.12).aspx)

```
using (var listsWS = new ListsService(url, cookie))
{
    string updateXml = string.Format("<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>{0}</Field><Field Name='MetaInfo' Property='vti_contenttypeorder'>0x010100E1A96B0CF4FC4C4E8EABF3AB52EED1A3</Field></Method></Batch>", itemId);
    var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(updateXml); 
    listsWS.UpdateListItems(list.Id.ToString(), doc.SelectSingleNode("//Batch"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of clarity, there are two properties:

- [UniqueContentTypeOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.uniquecontenttypeorder(v=office.15).aspx)
- [ContentTypeOrder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.contenttypeorder(v=office.15).aspx)

ContentTypeOrder is a read-only field but if you're working with folders, you can use the property `UniqueContentTypeOrder` (available in CSOM) like so:

> Folder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = ContentTypeOrder//maybe some additional tweaking

I actually made a working proof of concept sometime ago to change the `vti_contenttypeorder` property through CSOM. The `UniqueContentTypeOrder` property didn't work as it did not allow me to actually remove content types, just set the order.

```
clientContext.load(folder, 'Name', 'UniqueContentTypeOrder', 'ContentTypeOrder', 'Properties');
...
//construct the contentTypeString (comma separated string of content types)
...
var folderProps = folder.get_properties();
folderProps.set_item("vti_contenttypeorder", contentTypeString);
folder.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(...);
```

More:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979628/difference-between-contenttypeorder-and-uniquecontenttypeorder